# php foreach inside foreach: what is the error?

Tags: foreach

I want the code to be executed only if i>10. Can you please say what the error is?

```
<?php $data = wp_excel_cms_get("top100"); ?>


<?php foreach($data as $entry): 

  { 
foreach($entry as $entry[i>10]): 
<?php echo $entry[0]."&nbsp;";?><a href ="<?php echo "http://". $entry[1]; ?    >"target="_blank"><?php echo $entry[1];?></a><br />
  }
 ?>

<hr />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What is the error message you get ?

Comment: `foreach($entry as $entry[i>10])` is nonsense. You probably want `foreach($entry as $item)` or so.

Comment: You should show us what `$data` looks like as well as your expected and actual outputs.

Comment: I'm fairly certain your PHP logs are pointing you to a glaring syntax error here.  You have a `<?php` *in your PHP code*.  Aside from whatever `$entry[i>10]` is supposed to mean, that entire next line is one big syntax error.

Comment: Before `<?php foreach($data as $entry): ` line, type `print_r($data);` and enter the output or part of the output in your question. It will help us help you. Also, where is `i` declared? What is it?